# wrong UUID (primary key) is transferred from Spring repository with fetchtype LAZY and @ManyToOne

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a strange behaviour when I fetch an entity which is something like a "parent" to another entity. These are my entity classes:

**Parent entity ("one side")**

```java
package so.lazy;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Parent extends Base {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1111542804002616234L;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "one")
    private Set<Child> children = new LinkedHashSet<Child>();

    // more fields

    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parent{" +
                "dataId=" + getDataId() +
                '}';
    }
    // more getters and setters
}
```

**Child entity ("many side")**

```java
package so.lazy;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Child extends Base {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8798542804002616234L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;

    // more fields

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    // more getters and setters
}
```

**Abstract Base class**

```java
package so.lazy;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "data_id")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private java.util.UUID dataId;

    public Base() {
        dataId = UUID.randomUUID();  // production: com.fasterxml.uuid.generators UUID Type 1
    }

    public UUID getDataId() {
        return dataId;
    }

    public void setDataId(UUID dataId) {
        this.dataId = dataId;
    }
}
```

When I use this code:

```
Child child=childrepository.findOne(uuid);
Parent parent=child.getParent();

System.out.println("Parent: " + parent.toString());        // Output A
System.out.println("ID in parent: " + parent.getDataId);   // Output B
```

**The output contains two completely different UUIDs** for parent in output A and B.
The method `Parent#toString()` gives the correct UUID, the getter gives a wrong UUID.

**WHY ???**

If I switch to `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` for `parent` in `Child`, it works fine.

My dependencies:
Spring 4.3.8
Spring DataJPA 1.11.0
PostgreSQL 9.4-1202-jdbc42

Comment: The moment you do `child.getParent()` you should have the data fetched from db, and nothing should be different to be honest, I am also confused how can this be possible.

Comment: I think somehow the constructor logic is conflicting with the lazy loading order, can you try to put creation of random UUID in a [`@PrePersist`](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa) block with null check as my previous comment? It is more controlled, I'd assume that would be a solution...

Comment: @buræquete - sorry, no, I didn't try. The code in my question doesn't belong to a MCVE. In addition, there are many sessions between the creation of the entity (where the constructor is used) and the queries.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but the only code that can generate an invalid UUID is also within that constructor block, can't you at least give it a try?

Comment: Also what happens when you call `parent.toString()` again after you get correct UUID from `parent.getDataId()`, does it still return wrong one? Maybe the way `toString()` is defined triggers constructor somehow? Can you check its implementation?